# How to unlink image and delete from database using codeigniter in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have upload images in rooturl + uploads/slider
and image name store in database slider_image.

I want to delete slider_image from databse and also delete from folder.

my folder location :
`http://localhost/game/uploads/slider/soccer.jpg`

image_name:
soccer.jpg

I got an warning error :

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  unlink(): http does not allow unlinking

my model code:

```
public function deleteSlider($sliderID)
{
    $this->db->delete('slider_tbl',array('slider_id' => $sliderID));
    $path = base_url("uploads/slider/".$result[0]->slider_image);
    if($this->db->affected_rows() >= 1){
    if(unlink($path))
    return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: The string you have given represents an url, not a folder. As a simple approach: You need to find the absolute path to at least the image upload folder to then use unlink() on a combination of the absolute path and the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Changing your `$path`.

```
$path = base_url("uploads/slider/".$result[0]->slider_image);
```

to

```
$path = "./uploads/slider/" . $result[0]->slider_image;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$path = base_url("uploads/slider/".$result[0]->slider_image);
```

to

```
$path = FCPATH . "uploads/slider/" . $result[0]->slider_image;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the path to the file on the server, not the URL, so you need something like:

```
$path = "/uploads/slider/".$result[0]->slider_image;
```

without the `base_url`.